# Logstash - Parsing nested KV logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, elk

I have a problem with this kind of log:

```
<183>Apr 26 12:53:53 host.example tag_audit_log: type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1989212.965:15124458): pid=20982 uid=0 auid=427890281 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

I thought the simplest way to parse it would be with usage of `grok` and then pass it to `KV filter`:

```
filter {

  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:date} %{NOTSPACE:hostname} %{NOTSPACE:location}: %{GREEDYDATA:kv_message}" }
    overwrite => [ message ]
  }

  kv {
    source => [ "kv_message" ]
  }
}
```

Everything parses well, besides logs inside `msg` fields.
KV created an array of them:

```
 "msg" => [
[0] "audit(1989212.965:15124458):",
[1] "\\'op=PAM:accounting"
  ]
```

I am wondering how to parse further message inside of `msg[1]`.
I tried with `field_split_pattern`, but I am not exactly sure how to wrap it properly.
Some of the logs do not contain these nested fields, so it also has to be considered.

Comment: You might want to try the [`recursive` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-recursive) of the `kv` filter.

Comment: @Val good idea, but unfortunately outcome is the same. It's probably because `msg[1]` starts with `'`

Comment: Maybe you could use [`trim_value`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-trim_value) to remove the single quote and then recursive could work. Try it out

Comment: Yes, i did that with `remove_char_value => "\\'"` but still not getting rest of the log from `msg[1]`: `"op" => "PAM:accounting"`

Comment: Even with `recursive => true`?

Comment: Yes. I am wondering if `field_split_pattern` option has to be used here, but I don't have any idea how to wrap it up.

EDIT:

Sorry, it worked indeed, with small exception where `"op" => "PAM:accounting"` is still attached to `msg[1]`, what make me a bit confused. 
Rest of the fields are parsed in proper way separately.

Comment: You can rename `[msg][op]` to `[op]` and you should have all your fields

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to configure the `kv` filter to remove the single quote and recursively parse the values inside the second `msg` field using the following configuration:

```
kv {
  source => [ "kv_message" ]
  remove_char_value => "\\'"
  recursive => true
}
```

Additionally, you can then rename the `msg` array elements

```
mutate {
  rename => {
    "[msg][0]" => "[msg]"
    "[msg][1]" => "[sub_msg]"
  }
}
```

You'll get something like this:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2023-05-05T09:18:08.410Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "auid": "427890281",
    "date": "Apr 26 12:53:53",
    "host": "iMac.local",
    "hostname": "host.example",
    "location": "tag_audit_log",
    "msg": "audit(1989212.965:15124458):",
    "pid": "20982",
    "ses": "4294967295",
    "sub_msg": {
        "acct": "root",
        "addr": "?",
        "exe": "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd",
        "grantors": "pam_unix",
        "hostname": "?",
        "op": "PAM:accounting",
        "res": "success",
        "terminal": "?"
    },
    "subj": "system_u:system_r:init_t:s0",
    "syslog5424_pri": "183",
    "type": "USER_ACCT",
    "uid": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

It looks like unix audit logs with some fields added in front.

You may want to look at existing logstash filter online

## Solution

Else based on the single example you provided:

```rb
filter {

  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:date} %{NOTSPACE:hostname} %{NOTSPACE:location}: type=%{WORD:audit_type} msg=audit\(%{NUMBER:audit_epoch}:%{NUMBER:audit_counter}\): pid=%{NUMBER:audit_pid} uid=%{NUMBER:audit_uid} auid=%{NUMBER:audit_audid} ses=%{NUMBER:audit_sesid} subj=%{GREEDYDATA:audit_subject} msg='%{GREEDYDATA:audit_message}'" }
    overwrite => [ message ]
  }

  kv {
    source => [ "audit_message" ]
  }
}
```